# Why does adding a Django redirect stop database from populating?

Tags: python, django

So, long story short, I have been having issues implementing Django CreateViews. I am very close to getting this to work, but a new issue has suddenly arisen.  Without the redirect in the following code, my database populates new Model instances.  However, after adding the redirect to the success page, I cannot see new model instances in my database or in the Django admin page. Apologies in advance if I'm missing something simple.  I can post more code if necessary but my guess is that it's going to be something in either views.py or my template

views.py

```
class SuccessView(TemplateView):
        template_name = "success.html"

class DeviceChoiceView(CreateView):
        model = DeviceChoice
        form_class = DeviceChoiceForm
        success_url = 'success.html'
        template_name = 'index.html'

        ## All the code below this point is what stops the database from populating ##

        def form_valid(self,form):
                return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

        def get_success_url(self):
                return ('success')
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Port Reset</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Device Database</h1>
         <form action="" method="post"> 
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
         <input type="submit" id="deviceSelection" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest not overriding the form_valid function as it can lead you to override some important code, rather you can do this in less lines of code(better practice) by using **reverse_lazy**

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class DeviceChoiceView(CreateView):
        model = DeviceChoice
        form_class = DeviceChoiceForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy('success')  #view handling the success.html
        template_name = 'index.html'
```

Comment: So, I tried this and got the following:  django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'success' not found. 'success' is not a valid view function or pattern name.   I had tried this method originally, but then after experiencing this issue I was suggested to try using a TemplateView to call success.html.  My old question regarding this can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54929885/why-does-get-success-url-keep-directing-me-to-the-same-page-django  Any thoughts? I would ideally like to find the "proper" solution.

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    path('success/', views.success, name='success'),        
]     # the success it tries to find is the url name, so you need to define that in the URLs, also you need to handle the success.html in the success view for this method to work

Comment: Hmmm, okay thanks.  I will take a look at setting this view up properly and see if I can find a solution that way.

Comment: I managed to get it working this way by doing a VERY simple view that looks like the following: def success(request): return render(request, 'success.html')  Hopefully this safes me a lot of headache in the future. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You are are overriding the save() function that is normally implemented in form_valid(), so it is preventing the form from committing to the DB.

```
model = form.save(commit=False)
model.save()
```

Add that before you return the redirect.

Comment: This solution did work for me, but per @Paritosh Wadhavane I restructred my code a little bit to save some headache later on.  Thanks though!